# mmenu plugin jquery not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

Im using the jquery mmenu plugin for a responsive menu, the thing is that im trying to use it with anchor tags and i want to achieve this effect: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/xmpl-onepage.html

but when i click on of the menu elements, it just activates de anchor tags and doesnt fire the cool effect that closes the menu and takes the screen to the desired anchor. Here is my code:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $menu = $('nav#menu-right'),
    $html = $('html, body');

    $menu.mmenu();
    $menu.find( '.menu_movil_boton_ind > a' ).on('click',function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        //  if the clicked link is linked to an anchor, scroll the page to that anchor 
        if (href.slice( 0, 1 )=='#'){
          $menu.one('closed.mm',function(){

              setTimeout(function(){$html.animate({scrollTop: $(href).offset().top});}, 10
              );  
            }

          );            
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

html:

```
<div id="servicios_cont_gral">
  <div id="servicios_central">
    <div id="servicios_central_info">
      <div class="titulos_secciones">
        <div class="titulos_secciones_titulo">
          <h2><img src="images/servicios/vineta.png">Nuestros Servicios</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="titulos_secciones_subtitulo2">
          <h3>Nos inspiras, creamos y no dejamos de innovar.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="servicios_movil_botones_cont">
        <div class="servicios_movil_boton_ind_cont"><a href="#"><img src="animacion_servicios/images/movil/fondo-boton-1.png"></a></div>
        <div class="servicios_movil_boton_ind_cont"><a href="#"><img src="animacion_servicios/images/movil/fondo-boton-2.png"></a></div>
        <div class="servicios_movil_boton_ind_cont"><a href="#"><img src="animacion_servicios/images/movil/fondo-boton-3.png"></a></div>
        <div class="servicios_movil_boton_ind_cont"><a href="#"><img src="animacion_servicios/images/movil/fondo-boton-4.png"></a></div>
        <div class="servicios_movil_boton_ind_cont"><a href="#"><img src="animacion_servicios/images/movil/fondo-boton-5.png"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="contenedor_items_menu">
        <div class="menu_item5"><a href="#produccion_audiovisual" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(5)">Producción Audiovisual</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item5_hover" style='display:none'><a href="#produccion_audiovisual" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(5)">Producción Audiovisual</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item1"><a href="#disenoweb_multimedia" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(1)">Diseño Web y Multimedia</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item1_hover" style='display:none'><a href="#disenoweb_multimedia" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(1)">Diseño Web y Multimedia</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item2"><a href="#animacion_post-produccion" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(2)">Animación y Post-Producción</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item2_hover" style='display:none'><a href="#animacion_post-produccion" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(2)">Animación y Post-Producción</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item3"><a href="#fotografia_especializada" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(3)">Fotografía Especializada</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item3_hover" style='display:none'><a href="#fotografia_especializada" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(3)">Fotografía Especializada</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item4"><a href="#disenografico_ilustracion" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(4)">Diseño Gráfico e Ilustración</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item4_hover" style='display:none'><a href="#disenografico_ilustracion" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="servicios(4)">Diseño Gráfico e Ilustración</a></div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="ant_servicios" id="ant_servicios" value="5"/>
      <div class="servicios_contenedor_explicacion">
        <div class="cont_1" style="display:none;">
          <div class="icono_bg1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_2" style="display: none;">
          <div class="icono_bg2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_3" style="display: none;">
          <div class="icono_bg3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_4" style="display: none;">
          <div class="icono_bg4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_5" style="display:none;">
          <div class="icono_bg5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_5">
          <div class="float-right">
            <div id="servicio_titulo_naranja">Producción Audiovisual</div>
            <div id="servicio_titulo_azul">Dando movimiento a tus ideas.</div>
            <div id="servicio_explicacion_gris">Comprendemos que la imagen que proyectas frente tus clientes es uno de los valores más importantes para tu empresa.<br>
              <br>
              Es por eso que te ofrecemos nuestra experiencia en la realización de piezas audiovisuales de todo tipo y del más alto nivel para que proyectes tus ideas de la manera más creativa e impactante. No importa si es institucional, comercial, videoclip, viral, infomercial, corto o largometraje, tenemos los mejores profesionales que te acompañaran para desarrollar un concepto que muestre tu empresa como de verdad quieres que la vean.<br>
              <br>
              <div id="escribenos_boton_servicios"><a href="#escribenos"><img src="images/boton-contactanos.png" width="139" height="26" alt="escribenos" longdesc="escribenos"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_1" style="display: none">
          <div class="float-right">
            <div id="servicio_titulo_naranja">Diseño Web y Multimedia</div>
            <div id="servicio_titulo_azul">Llevándote al mundo en un solo click.</div>
            <div id="servicio_explicacion_gris2">Sabemos que quieres mostrar tus productos y servicios de una manera llamativa, impactante y sólida ante tus clientes. Que lo logres, es nuestro objetivo. <br>
              <br>
              En MOBS Audiovisual, te brindamos todas las herramientas y maneras innovadoras para que dejes huella en quienes tienen contacto con tu empresa en la red, a través del diseño de estrategias de difusión virtual con páginas web de vanguardia, apoyadas con redes sociales, e-mail marketing, posicionamiento en buscadores, multimedias interactivas con tecnología 2D y 3D.  Todo esto sumado a nuestro soporte, con el servicio, el apoyo y la asesoría de nuestro grupo de profesionales que están dispuestos a escuchar y comprender tus necesidades y las de tu empresa.<br>
              <br>
              <div id="escribenos_boton_servicios"><a href="#escribenos"><img src="images/boton-contactanos.png" width="139" height="26" alt="escribenos" longdesc="escribenos"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_2" style="display: none">
          <div class="float-right" >
            <div id="servicio_titulo_naranja">Animación y Post-Producción</div>
            <div id="servicio_titulo_azul">Agregando vida a tus pensamientos.</div>
            <div id="servicio_explicacion_gris3">Concebir una idea es uno de los trabajos más complejos y gratificantes que existen.<br>
              <br>
              Para nosotros, las ideas de nuestros clientes son el alma de cualquier proyecto. Déjanos darles vida de una manera creativa a través del uso de las más avanzadas técnicas de animación y post producción existentes y consigue el nivel de impacto que estás buscando. Somos especialistas en interpretar tus pensamientos y traerlos a la realidad de una manera atractiva e innovadora.<br>
              <br>
              <div id="escribenos_boton_servicios"><a href="#escribenos"><img src="images/boton-contactanos.png" width="139" height="26" alt="escribenos" longdesc="escribenos"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_3" style="display: none">
          <div class="float-right" >
            <div id="servicio_titulo_naranja">Fotografía Especializada</div>
            <div id="servicio_titulo_azul">Capturando tu mundo en un instante.</div>
            <div id="servicio_explicacion_gris4">Hacer realidad grandes ideas, imágenes simbólicas, valores estéticos definidos y comunicar nuevos conceptos es nuestro propósito <br>
              <br>
              El Conocimiento de los procesos fotográficos, la creación de un mensaje con contenido y la aplicación de la técnica adecuada permiten conseguir la fotografía deseada. Como especialistas no solo capturamos colores, texturas, diseños y espacios reales, te ofrecemos conceptualización y producción de imágenes que trasmiten.<br>
              <br>
              <div id="escribenos_boton_servicios"><a href="#escribenos"><img src="images/boton-contactanos.png" width="139" height="26" alt="escribenos" longdesc="escribenos"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_4" style="display: none">
          <div class="float-right" >
            <div id="servicio_titulo_naranja">Diseño Gráfico e Ilustración</div>
            <div id="servicio_titulo_azul">Te escuchamos, nos inspiras y creamos.</div>
            <div id="servicio_explicacion_gris5">Estamos en la capacidad de transformar gráficamente aquellas ideas o proyectos que tienes en mente. <br>
              <br>
              Ponemos la habilidad para crear e interpretar en imágenes tu identidad y cómo quieres que te vean los demás. Una imagen nueva, innovadora e impactante es lo que te ofrecemos. Logrando un concepto adecuado se desarrollará la mejor manera de mostrar tu producto ya sea a partir de creación de Imagen corporativa, piezas graficas o ilustraciones. Nuestra meta es que la esencia de tu marca quede plasmada en una pieza visual.<br>
              <br>
              <div id="escribenos_boton_servicios"><a href="#escribenos"><img src="images/boton-contactanos.png" width="139" height="26" alt="escribenos" longdesc="escribenos"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>cargar_actual();</script> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Fin Servicios--> 

<!--Quienes Somos-->
<div id="quienes_somos_MOBS">
  <div id="quienes_somos_central">
    <div class="titulos_secciones">
      <div class="titulos_secciones_titulo">
        <h2><img src="images/servicios/vineta.png">Medios Orientados a Buscar Soluciones.</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="titulos_secciones_subtitulo2">
        <h3>Nos inspiras, creamos y no dejamos de innovar.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="quienes_somos_cont_info">
      <div id="quienes_somos_fonso"><img src="images/fonso.png"></div>
      <div id="quienes_somos_cabezote_movil"><img src="images/cabezote-mobs-movil.png"></div>
      <div id="quienes_somos_intro">Somos una empresa joven, dedicada a diseñar estrategias de comunicación novedosas para incrementar el posicionamiento y la capacidad de venta de nuestros clientes. Contamos con una amplia experiencia en realización de piezas audiovisuales, post-producción, diseno gráfico, diseno e implementación web, fotografía especializada, planeación de campañas publicitarias y animación 2D y 3D, y la infraestructura necesaria para garantizar la calidad de nuestro trabajo.</div>
      <div id="quienes_somos_personajes_cont">
        <div class="staff_img1"><a>Ingeniero en Multimedia</a></div>
        <div class="staff_img2"><a>Diseñador Gráfico - Web</a></div>
        <div class="staff_img3"><a>Diseñador Gráfico - Ilustrador</a></div>
        <div class="staff_img4"><a>Realizador Audiovisual</a></div>
        <div class="staff_img5"><a>Diseñadora Gráfica</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Fin Quienes Somos-->
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any visual example we can't help. Please add a jsfiddle example

Comment: @Hushme hello, i uploaded the site here http://www.mobsaudiovisual.com/movil/ if u reduce the screen and press the button on the upper right side it displays the mobile menu, i want to reach this effect: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/xmpl-onepage.html